# opencv Mat_<uchar> iterator failed

Tags: opencv

opencv version : 3.4.1

```
    void drawOnImage(const cv::Mat& binary, Mat& image) {
    Mat_<uchar>::const_iterator it = binary.begin<uchar>(); // THIS ONE
    Mat_<uchar>::const_iterator itend = binary.end<uchar>();

    for (int i = 0; it != itend; ++it, ++i) {
        if (!*it)
            circle(image, Point(i%image.step, i / image.step),
                5, Scalar(255, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

This function make circle on detected edge on image for highlight.
On this code, second line, occur error below.

> Error: Assertion failed (elemSize() == sizeof(_Tp)) in cv::Mat::begin

Parameter binary is corner map, and image is original image that i used buuilding image.
I think that byte size problem so i checked it.
elemSize of corners is 3 and sizeof(uchar) is 1.
but i don't know how to solve this circumstance..

```
    Mat getCorners(const Mat &image) {
    Mat result;

    dilate(image, result, cross);
    erode(result, result, diamond);
    Mat result2;

    dilate(image, result2, x);
    erode(result2, result2, square);
    absdiff(result2, result, result);

    applyThreshold(result);
    return result; // result == binaray
}
```

output of this function is binaray.

Comment: what's the value of  `binary.channels()`?

Comment: the value is 3.

Comment: Why you have a binary image of 3 channels?

Comment: sorry my mistake, value is 1. and i add code about binaray.